# Nodejs json file writing

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, web

I am making a program that reads through an array containing hundreds of links, reads through each, and scrapes some text, then writes it in an output file as json.

I am having trouble formatting the json file, since `.map()` returns the json object like this:

```
{
   "id": "wajnh3ivnydeegrr",
   "lorem ipsum"
},{
   "id": "6yuyz57cmrgo5fbe",
   "message": "lorem ipsum"
},
```

Instead of a json array like this:

```
[{
   "id": "wajnh3ivnydeegrr",
   "lorem ipsum"
},{
   "id": "6yuyz57cmrgo5fbe",
   "message": "lorem ipsum"
}]
```

How can I push each json object into the array while formatted correctly? (the last trailing comma would have to be excluded, somehow). Really appreciate your help! The full request is below. The full code is available in Github [here](https://github.com/agomez314/rants).

```
app.get('/scrape', function(req, res) {    

   dataDocument.map(function(item, err) {

    request(item, function(err, response, html) {
        if (!err) {

            //Variables
            var message, id, date;
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var message = $(".messagebody").text().trim();

            //Get Id
            item = item.split('/');
            id = item[4];

            //Make json entry
            var json = {
                "id": id,
                "message": message,
                "date": date
            };

            json.id = id;
            json.message = message;

            string = JSON.stringify(json, null, 4, function(json) {

                console.log('Successfully written ' + json.id);

            });

            fs.appendFile('./output', string + ',', function(){

            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Note: data.Document is an exported array containing the list.

Comment: build an array and write once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to order your requests and know your first and last requests so we could use promises or simple nodejs lib called `async` there is a function called [`async.series`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) and use  [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) to build an array called `tasks` which will have a series of functions.
All functions will be executed under the same order of your `dataDocument` array.

To install `async`

```
npm install --save async
```

Then use the following modified code

```
var async = require('async');

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res) { 
    var tasks = dataDocument.map(function(item, index) { // create a series of functions to be executed in order 
        return function(cb){
            request(item, function(err, response, html) {
                if (!err) {
                    //Variables
                    var message, id, date , string ;
                    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                    message = $(".messagebody").text().trim();
                    //Get Id
                    item = item.split('/');
                    id = item[4];
                    //Make json entry
                    var json = {
                        "id": id,
                        "message": message,
                        "date": date
                    };
                    string = JSON.stringify(json, null, 4, function(json) {
                        console.log('Successfully written ' + json.id);
                    });
                    var output = string + ',';
                    if(index === 0){
                        output = '[' + string + ','; // first item
                    }
                    if(index === dataDocument.length - 1 ){
                        output = string + ']'; // last item
                    }
                    fs.appendFile('./output.json', output ,cb);
                }
            });
        }; 
    });
    async.series(tasks,function(){
        console.log('Successfully written all documents!');
    })
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not add the brackets in the right order. The commas are added just fine, but brackets are added randomly in the json list.

Comment: Do you have one `output` file and multiple `dataDocument` ?

Comment: dataDocument is one file containing an array of items: `module.exports = [item1, item2 ...]` and I would like to to output it into a single output.js file. Thanks.

Comment: This worked great! A little slow though, will work on improving performance later. Thanks @Ezzat

Comment: can you please explain why you return an anonymous function in the beginning while having the callback as one of it's parameters?

Comment: You have to read [async.series](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) to understand it.